# OpenGL ES 1.0 Android orthographic projection: Nothing in Emulator (but works on phone)

Tags: android, opengl-es, orthographic

this problem has left me absolutely clueless: I am rendering an OpenGL ES scene in perspective projection with some 2D overlays in orthographic projection. On my phone (Galaxy S4), it works flawlessly. On the Emulator, however, I don't see *anything*.
I have simplified the code to only set up an orthographic projection and draw a triangle. Can any of you shed some light on what might be the issue here? Again: On the phone, this code displays a white triangle, on the emulator, I see nothing. The following (simplified) code is called for every frame.

```
GLES10.glMatrixMode(GLES10.GL_PROJECTION);
GLES10.glLoadIdentity();
GLES10.glOrthof(0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
GLES10.glMatrixMode(GLES10.GL_MODELVIEW);
GLES10.glLoadIdentity();
GLES10.glDisable(GLES10.GL_LIGHTING);
GLES10.glDisable(GLES10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);     
GLES10.glDisable(GLES10.GL_CULL_FACE);

FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = OpenGLUtils.allocateFloatBuffer(4 * 6);
vertexBuffer.put(40);
vertexBuffer.put(20);       
vertexBuffer.put(40);
vertexBuffer.put(60);       
vertexBuffer.put(80);
vertexBuffer.put(20);
vertexBuffer.position(0);

GLES10.glClear(GLES10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GLES10.glEnableClientState(GLES10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
GLES10.glVertexPointer(2, GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
GLES10.glDrawArrays(GLES10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

(Of course, it's silly to recreate the vertexBuffer every frame -- but it makes no change in the (visual) result, if I create it every frame).
And for completeness, here's the initialization code for openGL:

```
GLES10.glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
GLES10.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GLES10.glShadeModel(GLES10.GL_SMOOTH);
```

The phone has a resolution of 1920 x 1080 (windowWidth/windowHeight), while the simulator uses 1024x600.

Some things I tried (without success):

- changed near/far clipping plane
- normalized coordinates of glOrthof to 0..1 (and modified the vertex coordinates accordingly)
- used Matrix.orthoM instead of GLES10.glOrthof to generate the matrix
- used different sizes for the triangle

Any insights?

P.s.: And yes: this is stricly GL ES 1.0 -- I might use 1.1 -- but I am not ready for shaders, yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem lies in the switching of PROJECTION_MATRIX and MODELVIEW_MATRIX on the simulator: For some reason, the simulator clears the flag "GL_TEXTURE_2D". I enabled it for the 3d drawing, switched to orthographic projection, drew the overlay, switched back to perspective --- and at that point GL_TEXTURE_2D was *disabled*. Enabling it on each frame solved the problem.